# MySQL error 2013: Lost Connection during query after 30 sec

Tags: mysql

Using *MySQL 8.0.11*. I am inserting 1 row into my ***artist*** table which has following structure:

[image]

My query looks like:

```
INSERT INTO artist(`id_artist`, `name`) 
VALUES  ('251874', 'Hetfield')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id_artist` = `id_artist`
```

Still after 30 seconds I am failing execution following:

> Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: From where are you running this insert query?  It sounds like the connection is not stable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Both trying from MySQL Workbench and Python script, but both fails.

Comment: Try increasing query timeout and restart mysql service

Answer (score 0):

Is your partition (the datadir of MySQL) full?